# Has PCIe related issues with Threadripper resolved?

Tags: pci, pcie

I recall that few months ago, there were some issues related to PCIe on Threadripper based Ubuntu systems. Have those issues been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really specific to Ubuntu. However, all of those issues you heard of should be fixed in the Linux 4.15 kernel, which is used in Ubuntu 18.04.

Those fixes may not be back-ported to 16.04 yet, however in a few months with the 18.04.1 release, there should also be 16.04.5 which should include the 4.15 kernel, bringing those fixes back onto 16.04.